# java-10x15 multiplication table (nested loops)

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops

I need to construct a `10x15` multiplication using for loops, if-else statements and while loops. Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image: what it's supposed to look like]

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
        final int IMAX = 15;
        final int JMAX = 10;

        System.out.print("   |");
        for(int j = 1; j<=JMAX; j++) {
            System.out.print("      " + j);
            // This printed the top header
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("____________________________________________________________________________");

        for(int i = 1; i<=IMAX; i++) {
            System.out.print("  " + i + " |");

            for (int j = 1; j <=JMAX; j++) {
                if(j <= i) 
                    System.out.print( i*j + "    ");
                else
                    System.out.println();   
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

It's outputting:

[image]

I'm so close to figuring it out but I've been stuck for 3 days now, and I still haven't used a while loop yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you need to convert one of your for loops into a while loop. Try searching for "convert for to while loop"

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should start using a debugger, if you don't know how then now is a good time to learn. It will help you a great deal with future syntax and logical problems.

Secondly, you need to move the call to `println()` to the outer for loop, you should only move down a line after `j` has become equal to `i`. For instance:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
    System.out.print("  " + i + " |");

    // 'j' should never exceed 'i', just make that the for loop condition,
    // no need for an if statement in the body of the for loop.
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print( i * j + "    ");
    }
    // move call to 'println()' here
    System.out.println();
}
```

You can also replace the nested for loop with a while loop, like so:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
    System.out.print("  " + i + " |");

    int j = 1;
    while (j <= i) {
        System.out.print( i * j + "    ");
        j += 1;
    }
    // move call to 'println()' here
    System.out.println();
}
```

Notice to that the inner loop will always run at least once, therefore a do-while loop can be utilized:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
    System.out.print("  " + i + " |");

    int j = 1;
    do {
        System.out.print( i * j + "    ");
        j += 1;
    } while (j <= i);

    // move call to 'println()' here
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**Full working code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);      
    final int IMAX = 15;
    final int JMAX = 10;

    System.out.print("   |");
    for(int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", i);
        // This printed the top header
    }
    System.out.println("\n____________________________________________________________________________");

    for(int i = 1; i<=IMAX; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d |    ", i);

        int j = 1;
        while(j <= i) {
            System.out.printf("%-5d", i * j);
            j += 1;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
   |    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
____________________________________________________________________________
 1 |    1    
 2 |    2    4    
 3 |    3    6    9    
 4 |    4    8    12   16   
 5 |    5    10   15   20   25   
 6 |    6    12   18   24   30   36   
 7 |    7    14   21   28   35   42   49   
 8 |    8    16   24   32   40   48   56   64   
 9 |    9    18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   
10 |    10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100  
11 |    11   22   33   44   55   66   77   88   99   110  121  
12 |    12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96   108  120  132  144  
13 |    13   26   39   52   65   78   91   104  117  130  143  156  169  
14 |    14   28   42   56   70   84   98   112  126  140  154  168  182  196  
15 |    15   30   45   60   75   90   105  120  135  150  165  180  195  210  225
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much!! helped me off so much..just one thing, the table needs to be  10x15 .. so do you know how to stop the table horizontally when j=10.. thanks again!

Comment: bassicly I'm trying to add a  j <=10; besides where you put the j += 1;

Comment: @HousseinKharroubi change the while condition to `while (j <= i && j <= JMAX)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `System.out.println();` after the loop and not in the else statement. Because it is still iterating through the second loop and printing those spaces

Answer (score 0):

heres is my updated code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Question2 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  

    final int IMAX = 15;
    final int JMAX = 10;

    System.out.print("    |");
    for(int j = 1; j<=JMAX; j++)
        {
        System.out.print(" " + j + "     ");
        // This printed the top header
        }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("__________________________________________________________________________________________________________");


        for(int i = 1; i <= IMAX; i++)
            {
                if(i<=9)
                    System.out.print(" " + i + "  |");
                else
                    System.out.print(" " + i + " |");


                int j = 1;
                while (j <= i) 
                {
                    System.out.printf(" " + "%-6d", i * j);
                    j += 1;
                }
            // move call to 'println()' here
            System.out.println();
            }





}
```

it outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMpxe.png)

I want [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57vA8.png)